# Spring bean get instantiated twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an issue of duplicate instantiate of a Spring Bean.
Normally I wouldn't mind, but the problem is that is is a scheduled bean, so we get our tasks beaing scheduled twice.

We use Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE in our pom file.
We have context.xml.
We use XML configuration and not annotation.
During my tries, I moved all the bean declarations under one context file, which being declared in the web.xml.

Here's the servlet.xml. it's empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd    ">

</beans>
```

Here's the web.xml part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>The App</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            META-INF/application-ctx.xml,WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    ... Other filters and servlets

</web-app>
```

And here is the context:
The lower part of it used to be in the servlet.context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/management-application-ctx.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/lucene-application-ctx.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/serving-application-ctx.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/tracking-application-ctx.xml" />
    <import resource="scheduling-ctx.xml"/>

    <!-- configuration  --> 
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="some class">
        <property name="location">
            <value>config.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="propertiesPersister" ref="persister" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persister" class="some other class">
        <property name="configSchemaLocation">
            <value>config.xsd</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    ... other beans


    <!-- This was in the servlet.xml -->

        <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="package to scan">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="detectHandlersInAncestorContexts" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/akamai/**" location="/static/akamai/" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true" />
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

The schedule bean (notice we use task and older scheduling method):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="aScheduler" >
        <task:scheduled ref="someBean" method="runIndexTask"
            fixed-delay="300000" initial-delay="300000" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:scheduler id="aScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
        <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
            <list>
                <ref local="credentialScheduledTask" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="credentialScheduledTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
        <property name="delay" value="10000" />
        <property name="period"
            value="${core:configuration:credentialScheduledTaskPeriod}" />
        <property name="timerTask" ref="cachedCredentialDao" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

To verify, I added debig log of Spring initialization. I do see, even after all the changes to one  configuration place, double instance of the bean.

What causes this?

```
26/10/2014 08:01:15,491 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:01:15,491 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:01:15,494 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'aScheduler' to allow for resolving potential circular references
26/10/2014 08:01:15,501 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:01:15,501 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:01:15,502 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:01:16,485 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:02:16,593 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:02:16,593 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:02:16,597 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'aScheduler' to allow for resolving potential circular references
26/10/2014 08:02:16,605 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'aScheduler'
26/10/2014 08:02:16,605 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'aScheduler'
```

Why does Spring create two beans?
I have only one context file.
In the import files, the scheduled bean tasks are not mentioned.

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You are scanning for all the components-twice. The `include` doesn't mean to exclude anything everything is still detected. Add `use-default-filters="false"` to disable the detection of anything else as the included patterns.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response.
I added  use-default-filters="false" to context:component-scan base-package="package to scan" , but I still see the same initialization twice in the log.

Comment: Where did you add it and make sure you are excluding the `@Controller`s in the root context. Also make sure you aren't loading xml files twice.

Comment: We've managed to solve the issue. we saw that the whole context was initialized twice. We changed tomcat's server.xml by setting HOST to root. there are some issues with the exploded war, which we are working on now.